# How do I adjust the orbit distance (radius) of OrbitAnimation?

Tags: ios, swift, realitykit

Right now I have

```
let animationDefinition = OrbitAnimation(
  duration: 5, axis: [0, 1, 0], startTransform: transform,
  orientToPath: false, bindTarget: .transform, repeatMode: AnimationRepeatMode.repeat)
```

I want the adjust the radius of the orbit. Changing `axis: [0, 100, 0]` does not as expected.

I noticed in the docs they pass `rotation` and `translation` but they don't document what they do and when I try to use them, I get

```
Extra arguments at positions #4, #5 in call
```

I'm guessing `rotation` and `translation` control the radius but I'm not sure how they work.

Answer (score 0):

Radius is controlled by the `translation` component of `Transform`. `translation` is not passed to `OrbitAnimation` but rather to a `Transform` object passed as `startTransform`.

So instead of using `model.transform`, pass in a `Transform` and set `translation` to the radius you want.

The parenthesis in the docs can be confusing. With this spacing it becomes obvious:

```
let animationDefinition = OrbitAnimation(
    duration: 5, axis: [0, 1, 0],
    startTransform: Transform(
      scale: simd_float3(10,10,10),
      rotation: simd_quatf(ix: 1, iy: 90, iz: 1, r: 100),
      translation: simd_float3(101, 1, 3)
    ),
    orientToPath: false, bindTarget: .transform,
    repeatMode: AnimationRepeatMode.repeat)
```